# Shared configuration for stylus and javascript

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, gulp, browserify, stylus

I am using gulp for the build system, bootstrap-styl as UX framework, and browserify as js bundler.

I need to store into a configuration file the different screen sizes used by media queries.

Stylus and the javascript application need to use these values.

Is there a plugin for building that ?

I have found for grunt-shared-config, is there an equivalent for gulp ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [json bif](https://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/bifs.html#jsonpath-options) for that.